# Is it ok to ask questions about web design on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have some questions of the nature: "Is it better to do  or  when designing a website to do ?"  Also, some SEO questions.

Is this an appropriate forum?

Comment: Some areas of the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page will be helpful like the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: there are different sites of stackoverflow like http://ux.stackexchange.com , http://math.stackexchange.com and so on .. . you can ask question on the site related to your topic like you should ask designing question on http://ux.stackexchange.com and others will help you but please try to search on google and stackoverflow before asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: But, ux feels way to specific to me.  The question I have in mind is not about how it will feel to the user.  It's something like "Is it a better practice to use images or formatted text for a banner heading", "From a SEO point of view is it equivalent to have a header be comprised of h1 test, or an image with h1 tags under it?"

That sort of stuff.

Comment: Speaking as a moderator on UX.SE it does sound like the sort of question suited to our site. Probably need a bit more detail to be sure though, but best practice questions for what to do on the front end (not implementation of how to do it) is certainly ok on UX.

Answer (score 8):

You need to registered at [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/about) for web design related questions.

> UX Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for User Experience Designers, Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about user experience.

For SEO ([Taken from](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38557/where-to-find-answers-to-seo-questions)):

You can now use the new "Pro Webmasters" stack exchange site, which covers most areas of web site development/maintenance, apart from programming/server admin which are covered by SO/SF.

http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Webmasters seems more like overall website management, not technical design questions.